# Pandas split DataFrame according to indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been working on a pandas DataFrame,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[-0.217514, -0.217834, 0.844116, 0.800125, 0.824554]}, index=[49082, 49083, 49853, 49854, 49855])
```

and I get data that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the index suddenly jumps 770 values (due to a sorting I did earlier).

Now I would like to split this DataFrame into many different ones, where each one would be made of the rows whose index follow each other only (here the first 2 rows would be in the same DataFrame while the last three would be in a different one).

Does anyone have an idea as to how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what were your attempts and what went wrong with them (if anything)? As it stands, it seems like you're making the other people do all the job, which is kind of rude, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` on the index from which we subtract an increasing by 1 sequence, then stick each group as a separate df in the list

```
all_dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(df.index - np.arange(len(df.index)))]
all_dfs
```

output:

```
[            col
 49082 -0.217514
 49083 -0.217834,

             col
 49853  0.844116
 49854  0.800125
 49855  0.824554]
```